# For what demand function is a monopoly most harmful?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, social-welfare, monopoly

Consider a firm with zero marginal cost. If it gives the product for free, then all the demand is satisfied and the social welfare increases by the maximum possible amount; call this increase $W$.

But because the firm is a monopoly, it reduces the demand and increases the price in order to optimize its revenue. Now the social welfare increases by a smaller amount, say, $V$.

Define the relative loss of welfare (deadweight loss) as: $W/V$. This ratio depends on the shape of the demand function. So my question is: is this ratio bounded, or can it be arbitrarily large? In particular:

- If $W/V$ is bounded, then for what demand function is it maximized?
- If $W/V$ is unbounded, then for what family of demand functions can it become arbitrarily large?

---

Here is what I tried so far. Let $u(x)$ be the consumers' marginal utility function (which is also the inverse demand function). Assume that it is finite, smooth, monotonically decreasing, and scaled to the domain $x\in[0,1]$. Let $U(x)$ be its anti-derivative. Then:

[image: monopoly deadweight loss]

- $W = U(1)-U(0)$, the total area under $u$.
- $V = U(x_m)-U(0)$, where $x_m$ is the amount produced by the monopoly. This is the area under $u$ except the "deadweight loss" part.
- $x_m = \arg \max (x \cdot u(x))$ = the quantity which maximizes the producer's revenue (the marked rectangle).
- $x_m$ can usually be calculated using the first-order condition: $u(x_m) = -x_m u'(x_m)$.

To get some feeling of how $W/V$ behaves, I tried some function families.

> Let $u(x)=(1-x)^{t-1}$, where $t>1$ is a parameter. Then:
>
> - $U(x)=-(1-x)^{t}/t$.
> - The first-order condition gives: $x_m=1/t$.
> - $W=U(1)-U(0) = 1/t$
> - $V=U(x_m)-U(0)=(1-(\frac{t-1}{t})^{t})/t$
> - $W/V=1/[1-(\frac{t-1}{t})^{t}]$
>
> When $t\to\infty$,  $W/V \to 1/(1-1/e)\approx 1.58$, so for this family, $W/V$ is bounded.

But what happens with other families? Here is another example:

> Let $u(x)=e^{-t x}$, where $t>0$ is a parameter. Then:
>
> - $U(x)=-e^{-t x}/t$.
> - The first-order condition gives: $x_m=1/t$.
> - $W=U(1)-U(0) = (1-e^{-t})/t$
> - $V=U(x_m)-U(0)=(1-e^{-1})/t$
> - $W/V=(1-e^{-t})/(1-e^{-1})$
>
> When $t\to\infty$, again $W/V \to 1/(1-1/e)\approx 1.58$, so here again $W/V$ is bounded.

And a third example, which I had to solve numerically:

> Let $u(x)=\ln(a-x)$, where $a>2$ is a parameter. Then:
>
> - $U(x)=-(a-x)log(a-x)-x$.
> - The first-order condition gives: $x_m=(a-x_m)\ln(a-x_m)$. Using this [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bmu1ilr0jp), I found out that $x_m \approx 0.55(a-1)$. Of course this solution is only valid when $0.55(a-1)\leq 1$; otherwise we get $x_m=1$ and there is no deadweight loss.
> - Using the same graph, I found out that $W/V$ is decreasing with $a$, so its supremum value is when $a=2$, and it is approximately 1.3.

Is there another family of *finite* functions for which $W/V$ can grow infinitely?

Comment: Zero marginal cost does not imply zero production cost. Who bears the burden of this cost if the product is given away for free, and in what sense does _social_ welfare is maximized then?

Comment: "Let u(x) be the consumers' utility function (which is also the inverse demand function)." $$. $$Isn´t it the consumers $\texttt{marginal}$ utility function ?

Comment: Without having read most of it, harmful depends on the concept of *social* welfare, and how we weight those two. If we only look at household surplus, a smaller price-elasticity allows the firms to reap more of the surpluses. Consequently, the demand function `D(p) = x`, is "worst", if we focus consumer surplus.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos By $W$ I meant increase in social welfare due only to the trade (maybe I should have called it $\Delta W$). In this sense, the production costs are irrelevant.

Comment: @calculus You are right, I corrected this, thanks!

Comment: @FooBar I referred to the common definition of social welfare, which is the sum of the welfare of the consumers and the producers. The textbooks (or at least those that I read) differentiate between a loss of welfare to a certain sector in the economy and a loss of welfare to the entire economy. The latter is called "deadweight loss". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadweight_loss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An arbitrarily large ratio should occur with demand curve

$P=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{Q} & \text{if } Q>1 \\
2-Q & \text{if } Q\leq 1 \\
\end{cases}$.

The monopolist prices at $P=1$, but the consumers' surplus if $P=0$ is infinite, because the area under the demand curve contains $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{Q}dQ=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reference where this issue is discussed? I would expect it to appear in standard textbooks in mircoeconomics, but didn't find it in any book I looked at.

Comment: I don't know of any references, sorry.